# Creating a random obstacle field in pygame

Tags: python, datagrid

I am trying to create a random obstacle field using various tetris shapes in pygame. I want to populate a 128x128 grid randomly using these tetris shapes. I am able to generate them and populate the grid using pygame.draw.polygon but few of them are overlapping on each other. How can I avoid overlap between different polygon object?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
import random

#Create discplay screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((768 ,768))
total_cells = 128*128
#colors
blue = (0,0,255); red = (255,0,0); white = (255,255,255); black = (0, 0, 0); green = (0, 240, 100)

def getShape(start, width = 50):
    a = random.randint(1,8)
    RT = [start, (start[0] + 2*width, start[1]), (start[0] + 2*width, start[1] + width), (start[0] + width, start[1] + width), (start[0] + width, start[1] + 3*width), (start[0], start[1] + 3*width)]

    LT = [start, (start[0] - 2*width, start[1]), (start[0] - 2*width, start[1] + width), (start[0] - width, start[1] + width), (start[0] - width, start[1] + 3*width), (start[0], start[1] + 3*width)]

    RB = [start, (start[0] + width, start[1]), (start[0] + width, start[1] + 2*width), (start[0] + 2*width, start[1] + 2*width), (start[0] + 2*width, start[1] + 3*width), (start[0], start[1] + 3*width)]

    LB = [start, (start[0] - width, start[1]), (start[0] - width, start[1] + 2*width), (start[0] - 2*width, start[1] + 2*width), (start[0] - 2*width, start[1] + 3*width), (start[0], start[1] + 3*width)]

    if(a == 1):
        return LT
    elif(a == 2):
    return RT
    elif(a == 3):
    return LB
    elif(a == 4):
    return RB

def drawGrid():
    screen.fill(white)
    for i in range(0, 768, 6):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (0, i), (768, i))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (i, 0), (i, 768))

def generateObstacles(perc):
    fill_cells = round(total_cells*perc/100)
    fill_count = 0
    for i in range(0, fill_cells, 4):
        x1 = random.randint(2,126); y1 = random.randint(3,124)
    start = (6*x1, 6*y1)
    ob = getShape(start, 6)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, black, ob)
    fill_count += 4
    print('number of cells filled',fill_count)

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((768 ,768))

    drawGrid()
    x1 = random.randint(2,126); y1 = random.randint(3,125)

    start = (6*x1, 6*y1)
    sp1 = getShape(start, 6)

    x1 = random.randint(1,24); y1 = random.randint(1,24)

    start = (6*x1, 6*y1)
    sp2 = getShape(start, 6)

    generateObstacles(50)

    pygame.display.flip()
    while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()`
```

[image]

Comment: When generating your random obstacles you could check for collision and if so discard the obstacle and generate a new one. Or you could segment your area into non-overlapping regions, and generate a single random shape that fits in that region.

Comment: You can use pygame [named colors](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color_list.html) instead of defining custom tuples everywhere. E.g. `pygame.draw.polygon(screen, "black", ob)`.

Comment: Thank you @importrandom. I checked for collision using shapely module and used a flag to generate the random shapes at random location again. The problem with this approach is that it is time consuming. let me know if there are any other approaches for faster implementation

Comment: Do you want your shapes to interlock, if not, then separate the board into 8x8 sections a generate a piece within that section.